# Android animation inconsistent between devices

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

Using view animations I set the x and y of a view to the x and y of the touch of the user. This animates the view in question to the desired position. When the touch event gets canceled the view gets animated by the same type of animation over a longer duration to give the effect of the view snapping back to its original position.

On high-end devices the animations works perfectly but on low-end devices the following happens:

When I use the debug option to show gpu renders and I drag the view to the desired position the whole screen flashed as expected. When I release the view only the block at the original position of the view in question flash and the animation is only visible once the view enter that region and snaps to the region on the time interval which it would have had to be visible in the view block.

This animation takes the same time on low- and high-end devices where on high-end devices the whole view flashed on release as expected in contradiction with the low-end ones.

I have tried using this code on different occasions

```
touchedView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE , null);
touchedView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE , null);
```

which improved the animations slightly but did nothing to the problem in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by disabling hardware acceleration for the whole app apparently there are bugs with hardware acceleration until android 4.3 but I might be mistaken on the exact version number as the information is not official